# Symfony4 route param order

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4

I have route with 1 slug, 2 int (category, page):

```
@Route("/articles-{categorySlug}-{category}-{page}", name="article.list.category", defaults={"page": 1}, requirements={"category": "\d+", "page": "\d+", "categorySlug": "[0-9a-zA-Z\/\-]*"})
```

**Good work:**

Url: /articles-categorySlug-5
Result: categorySlug: categorySlug, category: 5, page: 1 (default)

**Bad work (to fix):**

Url: /articles-categorySlug-5-2
Result: categorySlug: categorySlug, category: 2 (should be 5), page: 1 (should be 2)

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the category slug regex is greedy. Add a trailing `?` to make it ungreedy:

```
@Route("/articles-{categorySlug}-{category}-{page}", name="article.list.category", defaults={"page": 1}, requirements={"category": "\d+", "page": "\d+", "categorySlug": "[0-9a-zA-Z\/\-]*?"})
```

Comment: perfect solution! Thanks!